# try-catch exceptions in Swift

Tags: exception, try-catch, swift

Is it possible to catch exceptions in Swift? Given the following code:

```
NSException.raise(NSRangeException,
    format: "Now you've gone too far!",
    arguments: CVaListPointer(fromUnsafePointer: UnsafePointer()))
```

Is it possible to prevent the exception from crashing the entire program? That is, what is the Swift equivalent of the following in Objective-C:

```
@try {
    [NSException raise:NSRangeException format:@"Now you've gone too far!"];
}
```

Comment: this answer may also help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24010741/1249958

Comment: Sorry, should have searched more diligently before submitting a duplicate question!

Comment: You can add try-catch support for Swift by following the instructions in this article: https://medium.com/@_willfalcon/adding-try-catch-to-swift-71ab27bcb5b8

Comment: @WilliamFalcon, put it as an answer. Sometimes you have to interact with ObjC library throwing exceptions, your approach seems the only way.

Comment: it is possible in swift 2.0

Comment: Fwiw, I bundled @WilliamFalcon's excellent response (as updated for Swift 2 by ravero), into a Carthage lib available at https://github.com/eggheadgames/SwiftTryCatch. Hopefully useful. (Will, happy to contribute back, but I haven't added back CocoaPod support (yet)).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't have exception handling, [and this discussion in the developer forum discusses why it may be so](https://devforums.apple.com/message/970961):

> but keep in mind that Cocoa and Cocoa Touch traditionally don't intend
>   for you to catch exceptions; they intend for you to not cause them to
>   be thrown in the first place. Ordinary errors should be handled with
>   optional types and inout NSError parameters; you should address any
>   situation that causes an assertion to fail (which seems to be the only
>   exception-throwing mechanism in Swift) by writing better code.

Comment: That's very unfortunate. I'm aware that try-catch was never really encouraged in Objective-C, but currently there's no way to unit test whether Swift code throws an exception. `XCTAssertThrows` is not available in `.swift` tests, and without try-catch, there's no way to write a passing test that involves exceptions.

Comment: That comment from the forums is wrong. Foundation throws exceptions in a number of places that *need* to be caught for the program to function normally. The best example is writing to an NSFileHandle when the NSFileHandle experiences a broken pipe (e.g. a server writing to a connection after the client has closed the connection). There is no other way to detect this condition other than writing to the connection and it is a valid, non-fatal scenario. Without exception handling, Swift programs cannot implement server-like functionality using the Cocoa APIs.

Comment: I submitted a radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5287980646268928

Comment: I find it quite disturbing to throw error from the API, and don't let the swift language handle them. I just experienced the situation and really don't appreciate it. Sorry to be non-constructive, but some things need to be said

Comment: Swift 2 appears to now have this feature.

Comment: @TobyMellor: Citation / sample code (ideally for swift 3, now)? Swift still doesn't seem to let you `try` functions on a FileHandle...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, as of today, Swift does not support this. It will most likely be added on future betas.

Comment: Do you have any data  to back up your last sentence, or is it a hunch?

Comment: Basing my answer on the same documentation that manjolds posted on here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24023248/1011787.

`Cocoa and CocoaTouch traditionally don't intend for you to catch exceptions`, however they're still supported. That's why I said "most likely" — even though they don't encourage their use, they still provide that option.

Comment: probably, you assumption about _"It will most likely be added on future betas."_ is not correct according to the official docs, because they clearly indicate that it won't happen in the future either. you can throw exception in _Swift_, but it cannot be caught in runtime therefore those are always critical exceptions.

Comment: this is no longer correct, you might want to update your answer to capture possible votes