# How can I get stack trace error in Swift?

Tags: ios, exception, swift

In Objective-C, Whenever an application crashes, I can get stack trace to see where is the last method that causes the error by using this code in `AppDelegate`

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
 {
     NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&myExceptionHandler);
     return YES;
 }

void myExceptionHandler(NSException *exception)
{
    NSArray *stack = [exception callStackSymbols];
    NSLog(@"Stack trace: %@", stack);
    
    NSLog(@"MyExceptionHandler");
}
```

and it will print the stack trace log to console which I can use to debug the cause of the problem instead of ending up at `main.m` with no information

So how can I do this in Swift?

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023112/try-catch-exceptions-in-swift

Comment: Note: Your code only shows stack traces for exceptions, not for other signal based crashes.

Comment: These `objectiveC` exception handlers can not be used in `swift`?

Comment: Answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift/31770435#31770435

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you correctly, I think what you are looking for is an ***exception breakpoint***, which functions just like a regular breakpoint but is called whenever an exception is thrown. That way, it will stop your application right where the exception was thrown, so you can see the method, line of code, and variable values at the moment of the crash.

This can be set by going to the *Breakpoint Navigator* tab in the *Navigator*, clicking the plus at the bottom left and selecting "*Add Exception Breakpoint* ".

[image]

The Exception Breakpoint can than be edited with various options by right-clicking on it and selecting "*Edit Breakpoint*".

[image]

Comment: This is not even close to the same as the StackTrace. The latter is needed in a stringified form in production mode not just inside a playground/sandbox.

Comment: It isn't a stack trace but it can kind of fill a similar purpose for some users.