# Handle all unhandled exceptions swift

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any function like this

> void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs
>   e)

like in windows phone,for handling all exceptions to send to my server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` in your `AppDelegate`, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7896769/2710486)

But `Swift` <strike>does not fully support it</strike>, as explain in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25442521/2710486), you need to do it in `Objective-C`

**EDIT**

Thanks for Martin R's comment, Swift now supports it.

Comment: As of Swift 2, you can set NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler in Swift as well, see  the second answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31770435/1187415.

Comment: But note that this  catches only NSExceptions, not errors thrown in Swift or Swift runtime errors.

Comment: Thanks,i found what I want,and as @MartinR said its not catching  errors like array out of range etc...

Comment: @MartinR Does the Swift runtime run top of the Objc runtime and that's why setting NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler will not catch a Swift runtime error like array index out of bounds?

Comment: @Crystal: No, it doesn't.