# Detecting application crash in XCode/swift

Tags: xcode, swift, crash

For an OS X app with persistent state, is there anyway to programatically detect whether the last time the application was open, it crashed, or closed unexpectedly? (So I can perform some actions to ensure the application is in a consistent state)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect App Crash on Launch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33844313/detect-app-crash-on-launch)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler).

```
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
        print("Exception: \(exception.name) 
                          \(exception.reason!)
                          \(exception.description)")
        print(exception.callStackSymbols)
    }
```

The code I am using is...

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler {
    exception in
    ExceptionManager.handle(exception)
}
```

And the ExceptionManager class includes...

```
class ExceptionManager {

    class func handle(exception: NSException) {
        var exceptions = [ExceptionItem]()
        if let items = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("UncaughtExceptions") as? [NSData] {
            for item in items {
                if let exception = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(item) as? ExceptionItem {
                    exceptions.append(exception)
                }
            }
        }

        let newItem = ExceptionItem(NSDate(), exception)
        exceptions.insert(newItem, atIndex: 0)
        if exceptions.count > 5 { // Only keep the last 5 exceptions
            exceptions = Array(exceptions[0..<5])
        }

        var items = [NSData]()
        for e in exceptions {
            let item = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(e) as NSData
            items.append(item)
        }
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(items, forKey: "UncaughtExceptions")
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have already seen that answer somewhere else, and it does not work for me. Get an error:   a c function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a func or a literal closure

Comment: Can you post the code you are using. I am using this technique to log crashes with Swift 2, and it works for me. I don't have the exact code I'm using with me, but I should be able to post it in a couple of hours.

Comment: it's just simply calling another function I wrote in the swift class inside the NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler. Your code works fine, but I want to set and save a value via another function which gives me the error stated above.

Comment: NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
            print("Exception: \(exception.name)")
            writeToPlist(true)
        }

Comment: I have updated what I'm doing. The main difference is I'm using a separate class and class method. Does your need self.writeToPlist? Or just take the simple path and copy what I'm doing.