# Cannot receive crash reports

Tags: swift, google-analytics, crash-reports

As Parse crash report is depreciating, we are moving to Google Analytics.
I follow the guide to and receive view tracking and exception reports successfully.

here is how I setup the GA

```
// Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
        var configureError:NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
        assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

        // Optional: configure GAI options.
        let gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
        gai.trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXX-1")
        gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
        gai.dispatchInterval = 1
        gai.defaultTracker.allowIDFACollection = true

        #if DEBUG
            gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose  // remove before app release
        #endif
```

And I tried to make a crash by (in AppDelegate.swift didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ):

```
delay(20.0) { () -> () in
    let _ = [String]()[10];
}
```

And I can't get any crash report from GA dashboard.

I've tried to move this line to an IBAction, but failed.

My testing steps:

1. debug on device ->(20s)-> crash
2. debug on device 2nd time ->(20s)-> crash
3. run the app without debugging ->(20s)-> crash
4. run the app without debugging  ->(20s)-> crash

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Google Analytics only supports reporting of uncaught Objective-C exceptions.  It does not report Swift throws.  The following creates a Swift throw (and is not reported by GA):

```
    let crashArray:Array = [0]
    crashArray[1]
```

The following does create an Objective-C exception and is reported by GA:

```
    let array = NSArray()
    let _ = array.objectAtIndex(99)
```

Some useful information here...

[How should I use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift)

We can force an Objective-C exception from within Swift by using the following command (i.e. from within a catch).

```
    let error = NSError(domain: "Some error.", code: 0, userInfo: nil)
    NSException.raise("Exception", format:"Error: %@", arguments:getVaList([error ?? "nil"]))
```

There is not a way I can find to automatically capture all throws and relay them as an Objective-C exception.

Comment: Agree. That's why I move to crashlytics. They do really well for swift crash report while comparing with GA.