# Is there any way to handle unknown exception

Tags: swift, exception

I am trying to catch some exception that I don't know it will be throw in my code. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: do{ code that can potentially throw} catch {/*Any exception is caught here*/}

Comment: Is your question about try/throw/catch (which are *errors*, not *exceptions*)? Or about NSExceptions? Or about runtime exceptions (like "index out of range" or "unexpectedly found nil")?

Comment: @MartinR It's about all exception as you say. Do I need to handle all of it by myself. Is there any easier way like .net c#? Thanks!

Comment: These are all different. You need a do/try/catch for a throwing function. NSException can be caught globally (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift), and runtime exceptions *cannot* be caught as far as I know.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for your help! But how about external library/framework we can not handle their exception also, right? Oh no

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catching NSException in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift)