# How to intercept EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when unwrapping Nil

Tags: ios, swift, exception, signals

I am building some rudimentary crash logging system based on [this blog post](http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=423) (***Yes***, I am aware of PLCRashReporter, and ***No***, I can't use it and need to roll my own, however limited. Thank you).

My code registers both an *exception* handler (with `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler()`) and a *signal* handler for most signals:

```
SIGQUIT
SIGILL
SIGTRAP
SIGABRT
SIGEMT
SIGFPE
SIGBUS
SIGSEGV
SIGSYS
SIGPIPE
SIGALRM
SIGXCPU
SIGXFSZ
```

It seems to work fine with basic Objective-C stuff such  as "unrecognized selector sent to instance...", etc.

---

Next, I tried it with the following **Swift** code:

```
var empty:String! = nil

let index = empty.startIndex // < KA-BOOM!
```

...but the thrown exception `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` is not caught (my handler is not called), and instead I get the familiar:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

...in the Xcode console.

**What am I missing?**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38459885/433373) says that this kind of runtime error can be handled with `SIGTRAP`; however I am already handling that signal and it doesn't seem to work.

---

**ADDENDUM:** It seems there is no centralized exception handling system in place  for Swift runtime errors (out of bounds, nil unwrap, etc.); see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38738365/433373). However, Xcode is still able to crash with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`, so my question stands: How is this possible, and why can't my signal handlers  handle this?

---

**ADDENDUM 2:** Just to be safe, I tried registering my signal handler for **all** 20+ signals defined in signal.h (not just the ones listed above); still, no change.

---

**ADDENDUM 3:** Apple's official document [Understanding and Analyzing Application Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html) contains this snippet:

> #### Trace Trap [EXC_BREAKPOINT // SIGTRAP]
>
> Similar to an Abnormal Exit, this exception is intended to give an
>   attached debugger the chance to interrupt the process at a specific
>   point in its execution. You can trigger this exception from your own
>   code using the __builtin_trap() function. If no debugger is attached,
>   the process is terminated and a crash report is generated.
>
> Lower-level libraries (e.g, libdispatch) will trap the process upon
>   encountering a fatal error. Additional information about the error can
>   be found in the Additional Diagnostic Information section of the crash
>   report, or in the device's console.
>
> **Swift code will terminate with this exception type if an unexpected
>   condition is encountered at runtime such as:**
>
> - **a non-optional type with a nil value**
> - **a failed forced type conversion**
>
> Look at the Backtraces to determine where the unexpected condition was
>   encountered. Additional information may have also been logged to the
>   device's console. You should modify the code at the crashing location
>   to gracefully handle the runtime failure. For example, use Optional
>   Binding instead of force unwrapping an optional.

*(emphasis mine)*

Still: **Why Can't I Handle This With My `SIGTRAP` Signal Handler?**

Comment: How are 3rd party libraries like firebase crashlytics doing it, there has to be some way right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Signal handler works fine when debugger is **not** attached.

(We can even catch `fatal_error`'s `SIGTRAP` signal, and log stack-trace)

---

In order to see what was happening, I set up a small demo project where I registered a signal handler for `SIGUSR1` (one of the 'user-defined' signals available) and subsequently sent said signal to my process using the `kill()` function:

```
kill(0, SIGUSR1);
```

At first, I wasn't able to have Xcode's debugger jump to my signal handler, and instead it would stop at the line with the `kill()` call, highlighting it in red just as in my question.

After reading [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10431579/433373), it struck me that the debugger must pretty much *depend* on signals in order to be able to  stop/resume program execution e.g., at breakpoints.

Using the symbolic breakpoint specified in one of the answers:

```
process handle SIGUSR1 -n true -p true -s false
```

...I was able to make Xcode **not** stop on this command:

```
kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
```

...and instead jump to my signal handler, all while debugging. I could even step inside the signal handler and execute its statements one by one; display an alert view from within it, etc.

Although I am not able to achieve the same result with `SIGTRAP` (or even `SIGABRT`), my signal handler **does** get called (and my crash log **does** get saved to disk!) when I launch my app without a debugger attached (e.g., by tapping the app's icon on the home screen) and have it throw a Swift runtime error like the one I mentioned in my question.

---

My guess on *why* I was able to intercept `unrecognized selector sent to instance...` seems to be that, as an **Objective-C exception**, it is an entirely different beast from **Unix signals**, and has nothing to do with the workings of the debugger (unless you set up an **exception** breakpoint for "Objective-C exceptions"?).

The very fact that the handler is set with the unrelated function `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler()` should have been a hint...

*(I'm pretty much talking out of my limited knowledge here, so please feel free to add answers/comments with corrections as you see fit)*