# How to catch EXC_BAD_ACCESS when NSKeyedArchiver calls encodeObject

Tags: ios, multithreading, dictionary, exc-bad-access

A unit test that runs normally without problems, crashed now with error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT). Here is the relevant stack trace:
[image]
Obviously an element of an array could not be encoded, maybe because access of a dictionary using its hash value failed. Since this happened in an SQLQueue thread, I suspect that another thread did modify the dictionary during encoding.
The question is how to catch such a problem?

EDIT: I cannot enable the Thread Sanitizer in the scheme, since I have a Watch Extension, and this prevents it.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question is how to catch the crash?
If yes,

for Objective-C, `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`,

for Swift

```
signal(SIGABRT, handler)
signal(SIGILL, handler)
signal(SIGSEGV, handler)
signal(SIGFPE, handler)
signal(SIGBUS, handler)
signal(SIGPIPE, handler)
```

Update：
I searched just now, it seems like other guys had discussed it

[How to catch a Swift crash and do some logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325140/how-to-catch-a-swift-crash-and-do-some-logging)

Comment: Yes, my question is indeed how to catch the error. I guess in my case, I could try `signal(SIGSEGV, handler)`. But what to do in the handler? Set a breakpoint?