# NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler not firing in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, cocoa, error-handling

I'm trying to catch all NSExceptions in a Swift3 program - have been following [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift/31770435#31770435)

So I've got this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
        print("EXCEPTION CAUGHT HERE....")
        print(exception)
        print(exception.callStackSymbols)
    }

    // force NSException
    let array = NSArray()
    _ = array.object(at: 99)

}
```

but the exception's not being called 
Instead I get this output:

> 2016-09-04 14:49:14.252 catchAllErrorsTest[8126:164827] Failed to set
>   (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow):
>   *** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 99 beyond bounds for empty NSArray

I also tried putting the exception into AppDelegate (in applicationWillFinishLaunching and applicationDidFinishLaunching), but same result

Comment: The link you shared clearly states that it does not catch any Swift 2 errors `(from throw)` or Swift runtime errors such as accessing 99th index of array `[1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: thanks @ozgur - I agree that the link states it won't catch Swift errors, but it seems to clearly state the code quoted will work (it says 'So this will be caught:') - and it certainly looks like me like that should throw an NSException (though I'm no expert)

Answer (score -1):

I did as follows and works for me in Swift 3.
Define your NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler as a constant outside any method declaration in your AppDelegate:

```
let uncaughtExceptionHandler : Void = NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
NSLog("Name:" + exception.name.rawValue)
if exception.reason == nil
    {
        NSLog("Reason: nil")
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog("Reason:" + exception.reason!)
    }

}
```

This fires at any uncaught exception as this constant is evaluated as soon as your App Delegate instance loads i.e. at app launch.
Note: the Void type declaration removes a compiler warning for a Void inferred type that "could be unexpected" ;-) .

Comment: However it's not working for me- I've created a new Swift 3 project - I put your code in AppDelegate.swift - outside of any methods (directly below "import cocoa". Then in

Comment: ... argh... sorry ... Then in viewDidLoad, after super.viewDidLoad, I put the same code to force the error ( // force NSException
        let array = NSArray()
        _ = array.object(at: 99))

Comment: and I got "2016-10-16 20:16:45.345 testUncaughtException[3408:163505] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): *** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 99 beyond bounds for empty NSArray"

Comment: but the uncaughtExceptionHandler was not called

Comment: @JonCook Did you find any solution for this problem? I'm also facing the same behavior .

Comment: @SandeepKumar - sorry it's been a long time since I was in that code base.. I can't recall.. I just checked the code and i ended up commenting out that whole handler,but I don't recall what I replaced it with... will let you know if I recall