# How to do Global Exception Handling in Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

I want to catch exception globaly in swift ios

i have tried

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
  print(exception)
  print(exception.callStackSymbols)

}
```

but not working

please let me know the way with which i can catch all the exception of app at one place

Comment: No you can't. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737880/uncaught-error-exception-handling-in-swift and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift

Comment: Did you find the solution ?