# How to track production app bugs/crashes from all devices in iOS without using any third party libraries

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, crash-reports

I have one requirement like I have to track all the bugs and crashes from my production app of App Store from all devices.

I have idea tracking bugs or crashes by using Crashlytics library by integrating to my iOS project. And I have seen some other libraries too to achieve this.

But, my requirement is without using any third party library, I have to achieve this task.

And I know printing all the logs inside the apps and forwarding them to server by API call, but, if application gets crash app can't execute any code except Terminate delegate method. Even though we can't able to call the api request.

Can anyone suggest me, how to achieve this? I want implement this in Swift.

Comment: Maybe [Uncaught Error/Exception Handling in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737880/uncaught-error-exception-handling-in-swift)

Comment: Maybe [How should I use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift)

Comment: In my requirement, I have to track the list of bugs/crashes to know the developer from production app

Comment: Crashalytics send that crash report on next app launch. Not the same time crash appears. You can do the same. Save logs somewhere in a file. Handle Exception and write the stacktrace to file or log. On Next Launch send that file to server.

Comment: @RahulVyas I already thought that, But, I am looking for any other best suggestions would be there. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer from Apple docs.

About Crashes organizer
Use the Crashes organizer to view crash reports generated by the report service for apps that you distribute using TestFlight or distribute through the App Store.

Important: For apps released in the App Store, the user must agree to share user crash and energy data with developers. (TestFlight users automatically share these logs with developers.) Only the Team Agent or Admin role, or an App Store Connect user can view these reports.

To view crash reports, choose Window > Organizer, then click Crashes. Xcode begins refreshing the crash reports for the selected app version, including embedded app extensions. Xcode downloads the top crash reports—crash reports with the most number of occurrences on unique devices—that occurred during the past two weeks. However, there may be up to a one-day delay between when you first distribute your app and when crash reports are available in Xcode.

For more information, check here by clicking this link
https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev861f46ea8

Answer (score 1):

as per my knowledge if you have created an archived build from your machine and uploaded it to app store then you can open `Windows -> Organizer` from `Xcode` tool options, then in Organizer you can select the Crash tab at the top, you can see its automatically downloads the crash information if it has linked  with developer account. Also in itunes connect also you can check the reports.