# Swift variable declaration meaning

Tags: swift, memory-management

What's the difference between these two declarations? Which one is better? Why?

```
... error = some NSError ...
```

1.

```
var newUserInfo: [NSObject: NSObject] = [:]

if let tempUserInfo = error.userInfo as? [NSObject: NSObject] {
  newUserInfo = tempUserInfo
}
```

2.

```
var newUserInfo: [NSObject: NSObject]

if let tempUserInfo = error.userInfo as? [NSObject: NSObject] {
  newUserInfo = tempUserInfo
} else {
  newUserInfo = [:]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Swift 1.2, you can now use `let` with deferred assignment so you can use your if/else version:

```
let newUserInfo: [NSObject: NSObject]

if let tempUserInfo = error.userInfo as? [NSObject: NSObject] {
  newUserInfo = tempUserInfo
} else {
  newUserInfo = [:]
}
```

However, option 1 will *not* work, since there is a path where `newUserInfo` may not be set.

(note, as of 1.2b1, this doesn't work with global variables, only member and local variables, in case you try this out in a playground)

Alternatively, you could use the nil-coalescing operator to do it in one go, like this:

```
let newUserInfo = (error.userInfo as? [NSObject:NSObject]) ?? [:]
```

---

edit: Swift 1.2 added deferred assignment of `let`, enabling option 2 to be used with `let` now, but also changed the precedence of `as?` vs `??`, requiring parens.

Pre-1.2 answer in case you have similar code you need to migrate:

Neither are particularly appealing if you ask me.  In both cases, you have to have to declare `newUserInfo` with `var`, because you're not declaring and assigning it in one go.

I'd suggest:

```
let newUserInfo = error.userInfo as? [NSObject:NSObject] ?? [:]
```

Comment: Just found it http://mjtsai.com/blog/2014/07/25/nil-coalescing-operator-in-swift/

Comment: Indeed - looks like the precedence of `as?` vs `??` has changed.  Brackets fixes – `let newUserInfo = (error.userInfo as? [NSObject:NSObject]) ?? [:]`, however there's also the new option of using `let` with the `if/else`, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

- In 1. `newUserInfo` is assigned twice if the `if` branch is executed. 2. is better in terms of performance
- In 1. it's clearly visible that `newUserInfo` is initialized as an empty array. 2. makes the code less readable because you have to browse the code to know if it has a default value
- If `newUserInfo` can be set in several places (such as if it can be initialized it in several `if` statements), you should duplicate the `else` branch in 2., so 1. looks better

So: in solution no. 1 code is more readable, but solution no. 2 is slightly more performant.

Besides using @AirspeedVelocity solution (which is better than yours, no offence :)), I'd rather prefer to **use an optional**, setting `newUserInfo` to nil to indicate absence of value - after all, that's what optionals are for, isn't it? But of course that depends on your specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred pattern for this is:

```
struct TryUnrap<T> {
    typealias Tryee = () -> T?
    typealias Catchee = () -> T

    private var tryee: Tryee

    init(tryee: Tryee) {
        self.tryee = tryee
    }

    func catch(catchee: Catchee) -> T {
        if let result = tryee() {
            return result
        }
        return catchee()
    }
}

let error: NSError? = NSError()
let newUserInfo = TryUnrap {
    error?.userInfo as? [NSObject : NSObject]
}.catch {
    [:]
}
println("newUserInfo = \(newUserInfo)")
```

I prefer the above because I find it reads better for me. Also see answer 4 of [Error-Handling in Swift-Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010569/error-handling-in-swift-language) for general error handling using the same pattern.

Comment: This is essentially a non-idiomatic inefficient implementation of `??` for recovering Java programmers.

Comment: For me it looks more unreadable than the others, I prefer the first answers... but it's personal.

Comment: I don't find ?? very readable and it can't be used in other try catch situations either. However it is a matter of personal taste. The efficiency is almost certainly inconsequential, you are initialising a let which by definition is a one off.