# How to deal with null or blank in Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am fetching data from database. Sometimes it occupies values and sometimes blank. so my app crashes while getting blank. I even used ! and ? to avoid crashing.

In **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method,

```
cell.profImg!.image = UIImage(named: (profArr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("avatar") as? String)!)
```

App crashes while my profArr contains value

```
(

{

     avatar = ""

}

)
```

Is there any way to avoid crashing without checking variable length.

Answer (score 4):

```
if let myValue = profArr.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("avatar") as? String {
    // do something, value is not nil
} else {
    //do something else, value is nil
}
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to check, you can try something like this

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: ((profArr.objectAtIndex(row) as! NSDictionary).valueForKey("avatar") as! String?)!)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Alex Bartiş. But is there any solution to handle crashing without conditions

Comment: afaik not, why are you not happy with this solution?

Comment: @SimranJit , with Swift 2.0 new built-in error-catching capabilities were added. Check the "Swift 2.0 Update" in the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010569/error-handling-in-swift-language).