# Trapping signals in a Swift command line application

Tags: swift, signals

How to capture different signals such as `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` in Swift correctly? For example, when people stop my script by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, I want to do some cleanup before terminating it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Dispatch Sources](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsource)
can be used to monitor UNIX signals.

Here is a simple example, a Swift 3 translation of the C code in the
["Monitoring Signals"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html) section from the *Concurrency Programming Guide.*

```
import Dispatch // or Foundation

signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN) // // Make sure the signal does not terminate the application.

let sigintSrc = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGINT, queue: .main)
sigintSrc.setEventHandler {
    print("Got SIGINT")
    // ...
    exit(0)
}
sigintSrc.resume()
```

Note that this requires an active GCD event loop, e.g. with

```
dispatchMain()
```

in a command-line program.

Comment: Remember to `import Dispatch`!

Comment: @paper1111: You are right. It worked for me because my test code already imported Foundation.

Comment: Didn't work for me, the eventHandler never gets called. Does the whole programm need to be run in `DispatchQueue.main`?

Comment: @M.J.K: Yes. As I said, it requires an active GCD event loop.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something basic, but why does this work when all of the code is together in the main function, but if I try to register the signal handler in a class init, and run dispatchMain in the main function, the program blocks forever on sigint?

Comment: @ATyshka I had a similar issue where the signal handler wasn't executing.  As it turns out I forgot to also copy the `signintSrc.resume()` command which from the docs, "Resumes the invocation of block objects on a dispatch object".   So without this, the block was never going to be executed.  Maybe you also forgot to add this where you moved the handler definition?

Answer (score 0):

I use a simpler approach which is enough for my needs.

There is a limitation though. You can only access global-scoped things from the `signalCallback` and please check the @cobbal comment below for other limitations.

Just paste those lines before any code is executed in the `main.swift`:

```
let signalCallback: sig_t = { signal in
    NSLog("Got signal: \(signal)")
    exit(signal)
}

signal(SIGINT, signalCallback)
```

Comment: Only a limited set of C functions are considered safe to use inside of a signal handler. Since the swift runtime may call all sorts of C functions under the hood, it's unsafe to use any swift at all in a signal handler. From https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/sigaction.2.html :"That is to say, the behaviour of such functions when called from a signal handler is undefined.  In general though, signal
     handlers should do little more than set a flag; most other actions are
     not safe."