# Trap SIGINT in Cocoa macos application

Tags: swift, macos

I am attempting to trap a SIGINT for a UI application made for MacOS. In the app delegate class, I see the following method:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {

}
```

However, a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, SIGINT, never gets caught in here. Reading around the internet, has shown that this function is not guaranteed to execute, especially if the app goes in the background.

What can I do in the app delegate to catch a SIGINT? Or is there an alternate place I am to catch the interrupt so that I can close the resources appropriately?

Comment: No app delegate methods are called due to a SIGINT.

Comment: @rmaddy what can one do to trap them then? is it simply not possible to catch a sigint in a ui application?

Comment: By the way, why do you want to handle `SIGINT`? In what cases are you expecting that to be raised? It's generally not typical for a Mac GUI app to receive that.

Comment: You can use a “dispatch source," see [Trapping signals in a Swift command line application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713819/trapping-signals-in-a-swift-command-line-application).

Comment: @MartinR, I've updated my answer to address dispatch sources. The question is, if `SIGINT` is intended to interrupt a potentially runaway process, I'm not sure dispatch sources can be relied upon to trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Charles's answer is correct, but his caveat ("Be sure only to call reentrant functions from within the handler") is an extreme limitation. It's possible to redirect handling of a signal to a safer environment using `kqueue` and `CFFileDescriptor`.

[Technical Note TN2050: Observing Process Lifetimes Without Polling](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2050/_index.html) is on a different subject but illustrates the technique. There, Apple describes Charles's caveat this way:

> Listening for a signal can be tricky because of the wacky execution
>   environment associated with signal handlers. Specifically, if you
>   install a signal handler (using [signal](http://x-man-page://3/signal) or [sigaction](http://x-man-page://2/sigaction)), you must be very
>   careful about what you do in that handler. Very few functions are safe
>   to call from a signal handler. For example, it is not safe to allocate
>   memory using `malloc`!
>
> The functions that are safe from a signal handler (the **async-signal
>   safe** functions) are listed on the [sigaction man page](http://x-man-page://2/sigaction).
>
> In most cases you must take extra steps to redirect incoming signals
>   to a more sensible environment.

I've taken the code illustration from there and modified it for handling `SIGINT`. Sorry, it's Objective-C. Here's the one-time setup code:

```
// Ignore SIGINT so it doesn't terminate the process.

signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);

// Create the kqueue and set it up to watch for SIGINT. Use the 
// EV_RECEIPT flag to ensure that we get what we expect.

int kq = kqueue();

struct kevent changes;
EV_SET(&changes, SIGINT, EVFILT_SIGNAL, EV_ADD | EV_RECEIPT, NOTE_EXIT, 0, NULL);
(void) kevent(kq, &changes, 1, &changes, 1, NULL);

// Wrap the kqueue in a CFFileDescriptor. Then create a run-loop source
// from the CFFileDescriptor and add that to the runloop.

CFFileDescriptorContext context = { 0, self, NULL, NULL, NULL };
CFFileDescriptorRef kqRef = CFFileDescriptorCreate(NULL, kq, true, sigint_handler, &context);
CFRunLoopSourceRef rls = CFFileDescriptorCreateRunLoopSource(NULL, kqRef, 0);
CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), rls, kCFRunLoopDefaultMode);
CFRelease(rls);

CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks(kqRef, kCFFileDescriptorReadCallBack);
CFRelease(kqRef);
```

And here's how you would implement the `sigint_handler` callback referenced above:

```
static void sigint_handler(CFFileDescriptorRef f,  CFOptionFlags callBackTypes, void *info)
{
    struct kevent event;

    (void) kevent(CFFileDescriptorGetNativeDescriptor(f), NULL, 0, &event, 1, NULL);
    CFFileDescriptorEnableCallBacks(f, kCFFileDescriptorReadCallBack);

    // You've been notified!
}
```

Note that this technique requires that you run the setup code on a thread which will live as long as you're interested in handling `SIGINT` (perhaps the app's lifetime) and service/run its run loop. Threads created by the system for its own purposes, such as those which service Grand Central Dispatch queues, are **not** suitable for this purpose.

The main thread of the app will work and you can use it. **However**, if the main thread locks up or become unresponsive, then it's not servicing its run loop and the `SIGINT` handler won't be called. Since `SIGINT` is often used to interrupt exactly such a stuck process, the main thread may not be suitable.

So, you may want to spawn a thread of your own just to monitor this signal. It should do nothing else, because anything else might cause it to get stuck, too. Even there, though, there are issues. Your handler function will be called on this background thread of yours and the main thread may still be locked up. There's a lot of stuff that is main-thread-only in the system libraries and you won't be able to do any of that. But you'll have much greater flexibility than in a POSIX-style signal handler.

I should add that GCD's dispatch sources can also monitor UNIX signals and are easier to work with, especially from Swift. However, they won't have a dedicated thread pre-created to run the handler. The handler will be submitted to a queue. Now, you may designate a high-priority/high-QOS queue, but I'm not entirely certain that the handler will get run if the process has numerous runaway threads already running. That is, a task that's actually running on a high-priority queue will take precedence over lower-priority threads or queues, but starting a new task might not. I'm not sure.

Comment: Regarding GCD: I believe the information in [this old libdispatch-dev message](https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/libdispatch-dev/2011-June/000552.html) is still true. So if you create a serial queue for to handle the dispatch source, and you don't set the queue's target, the kernel will start a new thread if needed when the signal is delivered.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via the `sigaction()` function:

```
import Foundation

let handler: @convention(c) (Int32) -> () = { sig in
    // handle the signal somehow
}

var action = sigaction(__sigaction_u: unsafeBitCast(handler, to: __sigaction_u.self),
                        sa_mask: 0,
                        sa_flags: 0)

sigaction(SIGINT, &action, nil)
```

Be sure only to call reentrant functions from within the handler.

Comment: can you show how this can be added to the app delegate, and used to close down some resources? Something alike this post: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSignals/issues/4

Answer (score 0):

Although I won't dare to compete with the great answers above, I think there is something important to say that may simplify the solution a lot.

I think your question mixes two very different levels of MacOS program life-cycle management.

True, you can run simple posix-style executables on Mac - but a Mac Cocoa app IS NOT a posix app with "attached UI". Mac application relies on a very verbose, complete, and feature-rich life-cycle mechanism that allows much more than anything posix process can -- from state preservation and restoration (when killed/re-launched) to being auto-launched in response to opening a file. Energy management, handling computer sleep, background and foreground transitions, attaching to the same app on close-by device, modes etc. etc.

Furthermore -- I can't see how one can ever expect a 'ctrl-C' from the keyboard  to reach a Cocoa ("UI") application, as keyboard shortcuts are totally different in this context, and you can't run "UI" app from a terminal/shell synchronously.

Now the right wa to 'interrupt' a Cocoa app that is "stuck" or takes too long to perform something, is using the convention **command-preiod** key-combination, still widely implemented by many apps (Photoshop, video-editors, the Finder etc.) I'm sorry I could not locate this definition in Apple User Interface Guidelines - maybe it is no longer part of the standard. However, Ctrl-C certainly isn't!!!

you can implement Cmd-Period (⌘.) in your app (i.e. register for this high-level "interrupt" action, and handle it gracefully.

There is a good reason why NSApplication object wrapping the Cocoa App ignores SIGINT! it is completely out of context.