# Swift command line tool: notification on terminate

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a way to know if a command line tool is going to be terminated i.e when a user hits `CTRL-C`

Similar question to [Terminate subprocesses of macOS command line tool in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786443/terminate-subprocesses-of-macos-command-line-tool-in-swift) - **This hasn't been answered**

Comment: What about  [Trapping signals in a Swift command line application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45713819/1187415) ?

Comment: @MartinR that works, thanks so much.