# How to terminate a Process before exiting?

Tags: swift, macos, command-line

I'm new to Swift so to learn I'm trying to create a command line toot, in the code I'm running a node server using `Process`. The problem here is that when I exit the program the node process is still running and I want to end it whenever I exit the program or when I'm about to exit the program.

```
import Foundation

let port = "3030"

let process = Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/local/bin/node", arguments: ["/path/to/file/index.js"])
print(process.processIdentifier)
```

I found out how to get the PID of the process but I don't know how to kill it on exit or when I'm about to exit.

**Edit**

`process.terminate()` works, but the behavior I want is to keep the program running until it's killed manually (`ctrl + c`), killing the node process with it. I can keep the program running by using `waitUntilExit()`, however, using `terminate()` won't work if I use `waitUntilExit()`.

Comment: If it's not responding to SIGTERM (i.e. `process.terminate()`), then it may depend on the node process itself. If the program ignores SIGTERM, then you either need to rework it to not do that, or use SIGKILL. As a rule, you'd rather SIGTERM when possible.

Comment: Note that `Process.launchedProcess` was deprecated in 10.13 and replaced with `Process.run`. Probably doesn't matter here, but noteworthy.

Comment: @RobNapier ah thank you for the note. I should have explained better, `process.terminate()` does work. Will edit the original post explaining better.

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713819/trapping-signals-in-a-swift-command-line-application) suggests:

```swift
import Foundation

// Start the Node process...

signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN)

let sigintSource = DispatchSource.makeSignalSource(signal: SIGINT, queue: .main)
sigintSource.setEventHandler {
    process.terminate() // Terminate the Node process
    exit(0)
}
sigintSource.resume()
```