# How to catch runtime exception in Swift?

Tags: exception, swift2, ios9

How to catch runtime exception in Swift? I have found no mention of this. The current Swift try..catch only works for method that throws exception.

Comment: You don't "catch" exceptions in Swift. Nice explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24030038/2227743

Comment: I am trying to catch error caused by passing in an invalid identifier to storyboard.instatiateViewController.  Can't find a way in Swift.

Comment: I am asking a general question of whether Swift can catch runtime exception like Objective-C can.  The case I provide is an example, I am sure there are other cases.  Runtime exception by nature is something you did not predict.

Comment: On the latest version of Xcode, You can add a swift exception, on the break points tab, press the + button and choose swift exception