# How to force a catch from a closure?

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, swift4

Suppose the following situation in Objective-C: an array of blocks.

So I want to run a block, I do:

```
myBlock block = blocks[0]();
```

Now imagine that this line runs inside a `try`:

```
myBlock block = blocks[0];
@try {
  block();
} @catch {
  // catch an error
}
```

Now imagine that I want add a line inside a block to force the catch.

What I did in objective-C was to add this line inside a block

```
[NSException raise:@"Failed" format:@"Failed", nil];
```

Now I want to do that in Swift

```
let myClousure = closures[0]

do {
   myClosure!()
} catch {
}
```

The question is: what line should I add to a closure to force the same behavior, or in other words, to make the closure fail and the catch to be triggered?

Sorry if the question is stupid but I am new to Swift.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error-Handling in Swift-Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010569/error-handling-in-swift-language)

Comment: @MartinR - I started testing swift years ago. Then stopped using it because professionally no one cared about swift back then. A few weeks ago I started using swift professionally. So, yes, I am new to swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Objective-C, you use `@try`/`@catch` blocks to handle ObjC exceptions such as the one you are raising. In Swift, you use `do`/`catch` blocks to catch Swift errors that are explicitly thrown from a "throwing" function. Only functions (and closures) marked with the "throws" keyword are allowed to throw an error, and if you call a function that can throw, you must handle the error.

If you have an array of closures, the type signature of the closure must specify that it can throw, e.g.

```
let blocks: [() throws -> Void] = // get some blocks
```

At this point, you can (and indeed must) handle any errors thrown by calling these blocks:

```
let block = blocks[0]
do {
    try block()
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```